# Updating stock via Woocommerce API V2

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, api, woocommerce

I'm trying to update my woocommerce shop's stock levels via the API interface. I'm using the [kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library) but unfortunately it only seems to read product information and doesn't allow me to PUT stock info.

Reading the API docs I can see I can update a product using the following:

```
curl -X PUT https://example.com/wc-api/v2/products/546 \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
  "product": {
    "regular_price": "24.54"
  }
}'
```

But non of the function in the API client library access the PUT features of product,  I have found a modified client library for the V2 api [rodolfojnn/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/rodolfojnn/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/blob/751de835bb62123627a22c40a6037b180f2af0eb/class-wc-api-client.php) which has updated PUT functions:

```
/**
* Update a product by id
* @param int $product_id
* @param array $data
* @param string $method
* @return mixed|json string
*/
    public function update_product($product_id, $data, $method = "PUT") {

        return $this->_make_api_call('products/' . $product_id, ['product' => $data], $method);
}
```

But this now throws an **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['** error because of the **['product' => $data]** bit - I tried converting it to an array but that also errors, anyone any idea why (I'm running this in codeigniter btw)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try modifying

```
public function update_product($product_id, $data, $method = "PUT") {

    return $this->_make_api_call('products/' . $product_id, $data, $method);
}
```

Pass only $data as 2nd parameter to update_product

```
$data=  json_encode(

    array( 'product' =>

       array( 
          'regular_price'        => "10.26",
          'managing_stock'   => true,
          'in_stock'         => true,
          'stock_quantity'   => 45
       )
    )
);
```

Comment: i was missing manage_stock=true after setting this, I am now able to update stock_quantity thank you.

Comment: @Esen Can you please tell me how to update the price of a product ? I can update quantity but am not able to update the price